# ASP.NET and Entity Framework Customizing The GridView Field Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, entity-framework-4

Can you please let me know how I can Customize the header for fields in Grid View using Entity Framwork and ASP.NET?
For Example I have dbcontext instance which is showing on the GridView like this image:

[image]

Now I would like to change the Header Style, Format and Presentation to some thing like this:

[image]

I am gussing some part of job can be done through CSS styling like changing color but for Changing the `CONTRACTORID` TO `Contractor ID` I do not know how to do it?

Can you please let me know how to customize the grid view? Thanks