# How to Find out What Format of Entity Framework Model I have

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Can you please let me know how I can figure it out which Model format of Entity Frame Work you are working on? I have received an ASP.NET application which is running Entity Framework to connect to Database. Now I need to know what model format as:

- Database First
- Code Fist
- Model First

is used to generate the Entity Framework. is there any xml or metadata presenting this kind of information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Code first, you just have the classes.

Database first or Model first will have an EDMX that uses T4 to generate the classes from the model. Whether it was created from the model or by the user manually is irrelevant. You can update the model manually or from the database at any point going forward.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your perfect reply just having one more question. Can we separate the class to one stand alone class in Model/Database format? I mean as you know in these two formats all entity classes has been created inside the Entity.Designer.cs file. for boosting the class is it possible to have a Class in separate file?

Comment: The current version of EF actually does generate them as separate files. Are you able to upgrade? Alternatively, you could grab the T4 templates to turn EDMX into POCO classes and configure it to generate separate files rather than a single file for all models.

Comment: Can you please take alook at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103847/asp-net-and-entity-framework-customizing-the-gridview-field-header,  as well?